# LINQ-to-SQL: Why can't I use table name as parameter?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-sql

Why this is not possible:

```
... new DB().ExecuteQuery<String>(@"Select {0} From {1} ", selectParam, tableParam);
```

This throws thw following exception: Must declare the table variable "@p1".

Thank you

Comment: The `@` makes the string literal.

Answer (score 3):

```
@  before the "" says to compiler that this is a string nothing else
```

Read it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx

`Must declare the table variable "@p0"` seems to be different

`Edited`: Dont use table name as a parameter better use your table name only,it will cause sql injection please read

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thank you, @ symbol makes perfect sense, but this is not the reason why I can't use table name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error related somehow to [T-SQL Table Variables](http://odetocode.com/code/365.aspx).

---

@-quoted string literals start with @ and are enclosed in double quotation marks. For example:

```
@"good morning"  // a string literal
```

The advantage of @-quoting is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully qualified file name:

```
@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
```

To include a double quotation mark in an @-quoted string, double it:

```
@"""Ahoy!"" cried the captain." // "Ahoy!" cried the captain.
```

Another use of the @ symbol is to use referenced ([/reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) identifiers that happen to be C# keywords. For more information, see [2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I don't think that this is an issue as I have re-written the code without @ - the same exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite and answer, more a confirmation that it isn't anything to do with @"" strings, but it seems to be a limitation of the Parameter substitution in ExecuteSqlCommand and SqlQuery.

I have the same problem as you and found that you cannot provide the table name as a parameter. I have a command that is of the form:

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"Delete From MyTable WHERE MyColumn = {0}", someValue);
```

That works fine, but if I try to provide MyTable as a parameter it fails.

If you think about it the table name doesn't really fit as a parameter so it makes sense that it rejects it. However I agree with you that the error message is really not that helpful.